# Can't cross compile hello world program using g++ or clang++

Tags: gcc, arm, clang, cross-compiling

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I use this command

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ Main.cpp
```

And here's what g++ says

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/6/libgcc.a: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've also tried clang

```
clang++ Main.cpp -target armv5-unknown-linux-eabi
In file included from Main.cpp:2:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/iostream:38:10: fatal error: 
  'bits/c++config.h' file not found
#include <bits/c++config.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I don't know if it's important or not, but I'm using a virtual machine to do it (Ubuntu-i386 on VirtualBox).

Comment: Did you eventually solve this problem?

Comment: @AntonioKovačević  It worked with ubuntu 64bit. I don't know why it doesn't work with ubuntu 32bit.